# Warning: Possibly spurious solutions. [solvelib::checkSolutions]

Tags: matlab, warnings, solution, polynomial-math, symbolic-math

I am trying to solve four algebraic equations in a for loop. It is giving a warning 'Possibly spurious solutions'. Could you please help me to figure out how to remove it. Code is attached herewith.

```
a=[1.78E-05 3.39E-04    0.0104  -0.05791    -16.36];

for i=1:R/l0
    syms x y l r
    [sol_l,sol_r,sol_x,sol_y] = solve(l == (sqrt((x-x0)^2+(y-y0)^2)), r == abs((x+x0)/2),...
    poly2sym(a) == y, l*r*t == l0*r0*t0,x,y,l,r, 'Real', true);
    for j=1:length(sol_x)
        if (sol_x(j)<0)&&(sol_x(j)>x0)
            if (sol_y(j)<0)&&(sol_y(j)<y0)
                x_req(1,i) = sol_x(j);
                y_req(1,i) = sol_y(j);
            end
        end
    end
    x0 = x_req(1,i);
    y0 = y_req(1,i);
    r0 = R-l0*(2*i-1)/2;    
   end
```

Comment: What language is this?  Please tag accordingly

Comment: Why is `solve` inside the `for` loop? Nothing in it depends on `i`. You don't need to show all of that code to demonstrate the issue either, edit your question to strip out all of the irrelevant bits.

Comment: for every i, value of x0, y0 and r0 is changing. So the solution will change after every iteration.

Comment: I see and stand corrected. You still can demonstrate the issue without all of the extra code, simplifying and clarifying your question. Are the solutions actually spurious? Have you checked them? Or is your question simply how to disable the warning message?

Comment: Some of the solutions are spurious

Comment: You edited your code and it's now not even runnable. Just define your variables and call `solve` the very first instance generates the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your first equation to this, the warning no longer crops up:

```
l^2 == (x-x0)^2+(y-y0)^2
```

I'm not sure that you actually have spurious values though. The it's possible that the square root gave `solvelib::checkSolutions` trouble.

You may have thought that you had spurious values when you checked because you weren't outputting the variables correctly. You specify that `solve` solve for `x`, `y`, `l`, `r` (in that order), but then you name the output variables as `sol_l`, `sol_r`, `sol_x`, `sol_y` (different order). You must use the same order as `solve cannot guess bases on the names of your variables.

Your code:

```
R=30;
x0=-R;
y0=0;
l0=R/100;
t0=1.2;
t=0.7071;
r0=R-l0/2;
a=[1.78E-05 3.39E-04 0.0104 -0.05791 -16.36];

[sol_x,sol_y,sol_l,sol_r] = solve(l^2 == (x-x0)^2+(y-y0)^2, ...
                                  r == abs((x+x0)/2), ...
                                  poly2sym(a) == y, ...
                                  l*r*t == l0*r0*t0, ...
                                  x,y,l,r, 'Real', true)
% Check
sol_l2.^2 - (sol_x2-x0).^2+(sol_y2-y0).^2
sol_r - abs((sol_x+x0)/2)
[subs(poly2sym(a),x,sol_x(1));subs(poly2sym(a),x,sol_x(2));...
 subs(poly2sym(a),x,sol_x(3));subs(poly2sym(a),x,sol_x(4))]-sol_y;
sol_l2.*sol_r2*t - l0*r0*t0
```

The check returns small values close zero.

Comment: Could u please help me to understand why is it giving warning with l=sqrt () and not with l^2=()?

Comment: @Ankush: `sqrt` is discontinuous at zero and the `sqrt` of negative values is complex. Because `solve` is using a numeric method, there can be numerical errors and these could be amplified by the characteristics of `sqrt`. That's my best guess in this case. The non-linearity in the `abs` function may also result in more error as well – or at least make the solution harder to obtain.